# XML How to select Child Elements using XPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, nodes

I've got the following XML, shown in the following image:

[image: XML File]

But I can't for the life of me, get any code to select the house element between `<ArrayOfHouse>`.

There will be more than one `House` element once I've managed to get it to select one, here's my code so far:

```
// Parse the data as an XML document
XDocument xmlHouseResults = XDocument.Parse(houseSearchResult);

// Select the House elements
XPathNavigator houseNavigator = xmlHouseResults.CreateNavigator();

XPathNodeIterator nodeIter = houseNavigator.Select("/ArrayOfHouse/House");

// Loop through the selected nodes
while (nodeIter.MoveNext())
{

    // Show the House id, as taken from the XML document
    MessageBox.Show(nodeIter.Current.SelectSingleNode("house_id").ToString());
}
```

I'm getting the stream of XML, because I have managed to show the data in the MessageBox shown above, but I can't get to the individual houses.

Comment: Why don't you use XML serialization? Since this XML was apparently generated with XML serialization, it's probably the most natural solution...

Comment: Take a look at using [XPath Visualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/) for testing your XPath queries on XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the House nodes like this:

```
var houses = XDocument.Parse(houseSearchResult).Descendants("House");
foreach(var house in houses)
{
    var id = house.Element("house_id");
    var location = house.Element("location");
}
```

Or you can use `Select` to directly get a strongly typed object:

```
var houses = XDocument.Parse(houseSearchResult)
                      .Descendants("House")
                      .Select(x => new House
                                   {
                                       Id = x.Element("house_id"),
                                       Location = x.Element("location")
                                   });
```

This assumes that there exists a class `House` with the properties `Id` and `Location`.

Also, please be sure to think about the suggestion by Thomas Levesque to use XML serialization.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, how would I then loop through each house to get the `<house_id>` or the `<location>`

Answer (score 0):

With XPath you would need to use an `XmlNamespaceManager`, however as you have an `XDocument` you could simply use the LINQ to XML axis methods e.g.

```
XNamespace df = XmlHouseResults.Root.Name.Namespace;

foreach (XElement house in XmlHouseResults.Descendants("df" + "House"))
{
  MessageBox.Show((string)house.Element("df" + "house_id"));
}
```